# Using Listview In a custom dialog (android)

Tags: android, listview, customdialog

Ive created a custom adpater for my list view aswell as having created my custom dialog with a list view in it but i have no idea how to link the data into the listview in the custom dialog (im doing a really bad job of explaining this i know). My adapter uses a listview that has checkbox's and i would like to know how im able to store if there checked or not for the next time the application is open.
I'll put it into steps so its not so confusing:
I want to:
Create a list view with my adapter inside my existing custom dialog,
Store the state of the checkbox's for the next time the application is open.

(its not shown but my listview is called listviewdialog)

My main activity (just the custom dialog bit)

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
        dialog.setTitle("The List");


        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        text.setText("Did you not read the button? :P i'm not finshed on this yet XD");


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }
    });
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
package kevin.erica.box;

import kevin.erica.box.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_adapter, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter, parent, false);
    CheckBox textView = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    textView.setText(values[position]);



    return rowView;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part where you set up your dialog:

```
String[] mData;
// get your data; I don't know where its coming from
MobileArrayAdapter mAdapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(getContext(), mData);
ListView mListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listviewdialog);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: and then how would i put my data into that? :)

Comment: One last thing, it says MobileArrayAdapter cannot be resolved to a variable in the mListView.setAdapter(MobileArrayAdapter);

Comment: @user1337110 see edit above.  As for persistence, though, you're probably better off creating a database and adapting that with a CursorAdapter than with an ArrayAdapter

Comment: I have 2 errors with this. i get a The constructor MobileArrayAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String[]) is undefined error and a myAdapter cannot be resolved to a variable error, Anyway to fix it?

Comment: @user1337110 should have read your code more carefully - edited above

Comment: I'm being a real noob here because i find list view really hard but any help with the myAdapter error?

Comment: theres a typo in my answer - I declared it as mAdapter and used it as myAdapter :) fixed above

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10370/discussion-between-user1337110-and-jraymond)